# Trying to understand this VBA code about Userforms

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to make sense of this code I found online about VBA. I've been trying to push my Userform in front of all other apps, and apparently this code helps me do it.

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function BringWindowToTop Lib "user32" (ByVal Hwnd As Long) As Long
Dim Hwnd As Long


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Hwnd = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", Me.Caption)
    BringWindowToTop (Hwnd)
End Sub
```

I understand the second half pretty well; it's an initialization sub when the Userform starts up. However, what does "Lib 'user32' Alias" do? How does it know to find window?

Thanks ahead for your help.

Comment: Those are API calls that need to be declared in order to work. https://bettersolutions.com/vba/macros/windows-api.htm

Comment: You use them when you have to call the `DLL` procedure of Windows. Indicates that the procedure being called has another name in the DLL. This is useful when the external procedure name is the same as a keyword. You can also use Alias when a DLL procedure has the same name as a public variable, constant, or any other procedure in the same scope. Alias is also useful if any characters in the DLL procedure name aren't allowed by the DLL naming convention. [Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/declare-statement)

Comment: Those are Windows Application Programming Interface (Win API) where you can find the list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-api-list). In layman's term, those are sets of functions built-in to windows. It is simply describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/993478/2685412). How does it work? Simple, it is some sort of *default* instructions that *Windows* can understand. When properly declared and executed, *Windows* recognizes and interacts with the program or platform that calls it (in your case, VBA). Meaning not only VBA can use it.

Comment: If you want to know more about these *default* Win API's specific to *Window*, here's the [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-functions). It is in the same documentation I posted above, but points to the actual list of available window functions.

Comment: To know how to construct the proper declaration, see @braX 's comment.

Comment: If you love APIs then see this... From my [favorite site](http://allapi.mentalis.org/vbtutor/api1.shtml) of all times :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout That is my favorite too (although not secured, I wonder why that is). Even included in my browser's favorites. But if OP want's to understand how declarations are constructed and how to know the number of arguments, comments above got it covered :D.

Comment: @L42: I am sure :) I just shared an extra resource.

Comment: @SiddharthRout and L42: never heard of this site before. I've done fare bit of work with API's but never come across that site before.. will add it as reading/reference site in my vault :)